# Reverting Git Stash Pop

Tags: git

I executed `git stash pop` twice instead of once and am now getting the following warning.

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both modified:   package-lock.json
    both modified:   static_compiled/img/about-bg.jpg
    both modified:   static_compiled/img/contact-bg.jpg
    both modified:   static_compiled/img/home-bg.jpg
    both modified:   static_compiled/img/logo.png
    both modified:   static_compiled/img/post-bg.jpg
    both modified:   static_compiled/img/post-sample-image.jpg
```

Is there a way to revert the second pop?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule: no.  This is one of my many objections to `git stash` (not just to `git stash pop`, which is a particularly egregious offender, but to the entire `git stash` subsystem).

For some specific cases, if you can find the *second* diff that was applied, you can reverse-apply it.  Unfortunately, you've hit a conflict case and that's one of the specific cases where this *doesn't* work.  You're thus squarely in the general "no" case.

In the future, consider using `git stash apply`.  That means *do the apply step, but don't do the drop step yet*.  The `git stash pop` command means *do the apply, and then if you, Git, think the apply went well, do the drop too*.  It's the *drop* step that "loses" the effect that you got from the "apply" step and makes it difficult to un-apply in those (not all that rare, but also not all that common either) special cases where a reverse-apply / un-apply would work.  But that doesn't help you with what you are stuck with now.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I did the `apply`, I would then just revert the file via `checkout` and do the `apply` once? Also, what is a better workflow? I tend to keep various misc changes in the working directory, which sometimes creates situations like these. Should I create temp branches and commit changes which I do not know whether I'll keep?

Comment: I mostly use temporary branches, yes. As for undoing an apply: if you started with a "clean" setup, then yes, you can just check out (`git restore`) the files. The problem comes in when you've made some changes to some working tree files—so that the only copy of a *particular version of*, say, `file.ext` is the one in the working tree—and then you `git apply` something that makes *another change* to it. If that goes well (Git doesn't have a merge conflict), you can "reverse apply" the change to the the previous one back, but if it doesn't go well, you can't.

Comment: Yes, that is a common predicament for me. I will modify files in the working directory and will need to switch to another version because of another work. I may give `branch-stash` a go, where I create a branch-stash for a branch in which I am working.

Comment: If you have Git 2.15 or later, consider using `git worktree add` to switch to a new branch to do other work. This adds a *new* working tree (which gets its own separate index, HEAD, etc., as needed), leaving the existing working tree untouched. The checkout of the other branch then happens in the new, separate working tree. The `git worktree` command first appeared in Git 2.5 but there was a nasty little bug with doing work in one for >2 weeks that was not fixed until 2.15.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! So in this case, will I need to switch the work trees and then switch branches each time?

Comment: Once you have an added working tree, you can just open up a different window and "cd path/to/other-work-tree" in that shell, for instance. The work you're doing in each working tree will be in each working tree's branch; `git branch` in one of the two working trees will tell you which branch you're on. (If you normally use an IDE, this might be a problem: a lot of IDEs think they're smarter than everything else, when they're really ... not.)